# Problem with while() loop in code with sockets

Tags: c

I have simple while() loop in my C code but printf() doesn't work properly server connects new clients to him,and here is no problem with new connections.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int clients_fd[100];
int cnt = 0;

int main() {
    int serv_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(8080);
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    bind(serv_sock,(struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));
    listen(serv_sock, 100);

    while (cnt < 100) {
        int client_sock = accept(serv_sock, NULL, NULL);
        clients_fd[cnt] = client_sock;
        printf("cnt is %d", cnt);
        cnt++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: when calling C library functions: `socket()`, `bind()`, accept(), `listen()` always check the returned value to assure no error occurred.  If an error occurred, then call: `perror( "my error message" );` to let the user know the error occurred and both your error message and the text message from the system as to why they system thinks the error occurred, all to `stderr`

Comment: regarding: `int client_sock = accept(serv_sock, NULL, NULL);`  Just because the code overlayed the prior socket value does not mean the system has dropped the original socket instance.  Suggest calling `close( client_socket ); at the bottom of the loop  Note: before exiting the program also need to call: `close( serv_socket );`

Comment: OT: regarding: `listen(serv_sock, 100);`  the queue size could be as little as 3 and still always handle any new client connections (unless there are hundreds of clients trying to connect)

Comment: regarding: `int clients_fd[100];`  there is a system parameter that limits how many currently open sockets are allowed.  And the number of concurrent clients (in your posted code) is a max of 1, so no need for an array of client socket numbers

Comment: regarding: `printf("cnt is %d", cnt);`  the character streams are buffered.  so the `stdout` stream is not actually output to the terminal until either: 1) the buffer overflows, 2) an input operation is performed, 3) the function: `fflush( stdout )` is called or 4) the program ends, or 5) the output from `printf()` includes a '\n' (newline) sequence.  Suggest using: `printf("cnt is %d\n", cnt);`  Note the newline sequence at the end of the format string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is line-buffering here:

```
printf("cnt is %d", cnt);
```

so you don't get an output soon, since the `accept()` blocks. Just add a newline:

```
printf("cnt is %d\n", cnt);
```

That should fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help Sir!